# Hadoop run command java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop

I have successfully installed hadoop 3.0.0 stand alone to run on Ubuntu 16.04.
I created a jar using the following code from Apache hadoop tutorial.

```
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WDCount {

    public static class TokenizerMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
          while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
          }
        }
      }

      public static class IntSumReducer
           extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                           Context context
                           ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int sum = 0;
          for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
          }
          result.set(sum);
          context.write(key, result);
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(WDCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
    }
```

Creating WDCount.jar was successful with no errors

Then I created Input and Output folders and  Made a text file with a phrase in and saved it as fileo1.txt in the input folder.

I created this text to run hadoop on the WDCount.jar

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/Wordcount/WDCount.jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/Wordcount/Input /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/Wordcount/Output
```

When I run the code I get this message;

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/Wordcount/Input
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:232)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Include name of the class file containing main method after jar name

usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/Wordcount/WDCount.jar WDCount  /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/Wordcount/Input /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/Wordcount/Output

Comment: You are Welcome :)